# Found an UnExpected Error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, google-chrome

I have facing a strange problem. My project builded using .NET6 with Angular12 and successfully run this on mozila firefox browser. but in chrome browser, it's not work and i have found an error in console. I have noticed my Angular `localhost` is works, but when angular call the .net core api `localhost` then that time i have found this issue.

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/account/login', ok: false, …}error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/account/login: 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "https://localhost:5001/api/account/login"[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
zone.js:2707     POST https://localhost:5001/api/account/login net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

[image]

but this same web application project successfully work of my mozilla firefox browser. How to resolve that i don't understand. I am an absolute beginner. please help.

Comment: This article may help you:https://www.supereasy.com/how-to-fix-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-google-chrome/

Comment: I have not found actually this kind of page in chrome: "Your Connection Is Not Private"